# При конвертации canvas в DataURL выдаёт белое изображение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, base64

Проблема, собственно, описана в заголовке) Ниже мой код. Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

```
    fillCanvasHandler = (src) => {
    const modalBody = document.getElementsByClassName('Modal__body');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('display__canvas'),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = modalBody[0].offsetWidth - 20;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * 0.65;
    context.font = '16px Ubuntu, sans-serif';

    const title = this.state.displayAdsData.title,
          titleWidth = context.measureText(title).width,
          img = new Image();

    img.src = src;

    const posXTitle = (canvas.width/2) - (titleWidth / 2),
          posYTitle = canvas.height - 20,
          posXLogo = 20,
          posYLogo = 20;

    img.onload = () => {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / (img.width / canvas.width), img.height / (img.width / canvas.width));

        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
        context.fillRect(0, posYTitle - 30, canvas.width, 50);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillText(`${title}`, posXTitle , posYTitle);

        img.src = this.state.displayAdsData.logo;

        img.onload = () => {
            context.drawImage(img, posXLogo, posYLogo, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    const image = document.createElement('img');
    const imageForDisplayAds = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    image.src = imageForDisplayAds;

    image.onload = () => {
        modalBody[0].appendChild(image);
    }

    this.setState({
        currentImageForDisplay: imageForDisplayAds
    })
}
```

Comment: попробуйте перед установкой img.src добавить строку img.crossOrigin = “anonymous”

Comment: Не помогло) Но перестал отрисовываться canvas)

Comment: ошибок в консоли нет?

Comment: Вопрос решил. Проблема была в асинхронности React-метода "this.setState({})"